# BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: android

I have an arraylist which stores all the Uri's downloaded from Firebase storage.

I am passing this list to my CustomAdapter so as to display all the images in a ViewPager but, unable to do so because of the following error:

BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException:

MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(i, GALLERY_INTENT);
        }
    });
    show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pager =(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
            adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
            pager.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        pd.setMessage("Uploading...!");
        pd.show();
        Uri file = data.getData();
        StorageReference filepath = mStorageRef.child("Photos").child(file.getLastPathSegment());

        filepath.putFile(file)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        // Get a URL to the uploaded content
                        Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                        list.add(downloadUrl);
                        pd.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload done!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

CustomAdapter:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe,container,false);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(list.get(position).getPath());
    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    container.addView(v);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: it looks like `list.get(position).getPath()` returns incorrect path.

Comment: `Uri file = data.getData();` -- a `Uri` is not a file.